# UJS - where do I put the js.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ujs

My articles can appear on several sites, so as well as an article model with title, body etc and a site model with site_id, site_name etc, I have I have an article_site_permission model, with article_id, site_id and visible which can be either true or false.

On my article edit page, I've done a button_to:

```
<%= button_to 'Hide', article_site_permission_path(:id => @article_site_permission_id, :article_site_permission => {:visible => "false"}), :method => :put %>
```

This works - it changes the permission to false. And I can show the Show button which does the reverse.

Now I want to refresh the div that has the button in it by adding `:remote => true` to the button link.  But where do I put my javascript?

Is it in the article_site_permission view - even though I'm looking at a view of the article itself?
Is it called update.js.erb?

Thanks for your help.

---

Update for clarity.

My button is on the articles/edit page. The button updates article_site_permissions.  I want to go back to articles/edit and refresh the div that has the button in it.

I must edit the update controller for article_site_permissions, but where do I put the js to refresh the div?

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should explain everything you need to know. If things are unclear, let me know.

Comment: Updated again. What I've put should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, redirect to the action you want (index, show, etc.). Do a

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

under that action in your controller. Then, in the corresponding view, have a file named

```
index.js.erb
```

Or replace index with whatever action, just be sure to give it the same name as the action that's calling it.

**EDIT**

I should also mention you are correct in adding the remote true to your button. It's hard to tell from your question what action you're trying to reach in which controller. If you're trying to access the show action of the ArticleSitePermission controller, you're doing well. However, it seems like you're not trying to route to show. [Check out this link for more info on routing to different actions.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls)

**EDIT 2**

This should do it.

```
<%= link_to 'Click me', {:controller => "article", :action => "update", :id => @article_site_permission_id },
      :remote => true %>
```

Also, if all you want to do is redirect to the article, you don't need to do js. Just redirect to articles#show

Comment: I want to send data to the ArticleSitePermission controller, but refresh an article view - that's what I'm unclear about!  Sorry my question was unclear.  I've updated the question.

Comment: Yes of course - I just redirect (:back) in the controller to go back to where I came from.